# Проблема использования onRetainNonConfigurationInstance для сохранения AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

Я пытаюсь сделать сохранения своего AsyncTask при повороте экрана по этой [статье](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/154-urok-91-asynctask-povorot-ekrana.html), но `android studio` ругается на код:

```
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance () {
    playerTask.unLink();
    return playerTask;
    }
```

А именно на первую строчку, что я делаю не так? Может метод устарел и если да, то есть ли другое не сложное решение? (я делаю плеер со стримом)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно быть `extends Activity`, а не `extends AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: А моя задача обязательно static должна быть?